# Segmentation fault in executing a mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I am trying to create a matlab interface for an existing application using mex files.
I have successfully created the ***.mexa64 file and also able to run the executable once/twice.
But if I execute it more than two times consecutively it is giving me segmentation fault and matlab crashes.

The code snippet I have added is as below.

```
void  mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs,const mxArray *prhs[])
{
argc=nrhs+1;
argv=new char*[argc];
int i,j;


argv[0]=new char[(strlen("./learnwts")+1)*sizeof(char)];
strcpy(argv[0],"./learnwts");

for(i=0;i<nrhs;i++)
{
    j=i+1;
    argv[j]=new char[(mxGetN(prhs[i]) + 1)*sizeof(char)];
    mxGetString(prhs[i], argv[j], mxGetN(prhs[i]) + 1);
}
```

and also I have created a mexatexit function to delete the memory allocated thru new operator

```
void cleanup()
{
for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
{
    delete[] argv[i];
}
delete[] argv;
}
```

I am not able to figure out the mistake.
Has anyone encountered this before? .Can anyone help me in tracing out the mistake I made?

Comment: why this complicated interface? have you tried [`system`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/system.html) command in Matlab?

Comment: Are all inputs to mex strings? is it possible that some of the arguments are numeric?

Comment: I haven't tried debugging it.Will try and comment back.Yes all the inputs to mex are strings and there are no numeric values.I am naive to this system command and will try this too.Thanks @Shai

Comment: I am not very used to c++ yet and I do not know how matlab handles everything, but I am still a bit doubtful about the code. What I think happens is. You have one function that creates a pointer to an array `argv` and allocates memory to in on the heap. When the function ends the pointer goes out of scope but the memory is still not cleaned up. Then you have reserved memory which you can no longer access (memory leak). The function that is supposed to delete `argv` should not be able to do that since it cannot be reached (what happen here?!). Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @shai:I have debugged my mex file and there are no memory leaks.I am able to allocate and deallocate the memory for argv array successfully.Also I am having cout as printing statments to terminal in the original code and I left them as it is.Will it be a problem?.DO I need to replace all of them with mexPrintf statements.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Patrik:Here in the mex files the function mexFunction itself is the main function and it is not going to terminate till the program ends. So,I dont see any memory leak here. Also I copied the function itself in the mexfunction and tried and results are same.

Comment: Well obviously you must try to access reserved memory in some part of the code. Why not just try with vector instead? That one already have a proper destructor and that will as well make it easier for you.

Comment: @patrik:Thanks for your quick replies.I have tried the same as suggest by you but still the error persists. Also if I try to load the matlab with option 'matlab -nodesktop' then I am not getting this segfault.